# Finding a row with greater or equal value to the given number (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a **rank system** and ranks are stored in a database, my problem is about finding rows with **greater or equal** value to **given user xp**:

It's something like this:

**list of ranks in ranks table:**

name: *Rank1* exp: *400*

name: *Rank2* exp: *500*

name: *Rank3* exp: *700*

```
$xp = "500";

$find = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE exp >= '$xp' LIMIT 1");

if($find->num_rows > 0){
 // if a rank with greater than or equal value was found
  $rdata = $find->fetch_assoc();
 // return rank name
  echo $rdata["name"];
}
```

this returns **Rank1**, i don't know why :(

Can anyone help me? I'm not yet good in mysql.

Comment: if the exp is numeric you should avoid the single quotes around $xp  in query and assing a numeric value to $xp

Comment: Remove the quotes around 500 in $xp = 500;

Comment: it returns Rank3 even though the $xp is 450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the " " around 500, but for future reference I'd turn this into a prepared statement as your query isn't as secure as it could be

```
$xp = 500;

$query = "SELECT name FROM ranks WHERE exp >= ?' LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("s",$xp);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_param($name);
while($stmt->fetch()){
   if($stmt->num_rows > 0 ){
      echo $name;
    }
}
```

Another suggestion. Instead of selecting where >= $xp and limiting by 1, Why not select the range you're actually looking for? between 500 and 700 so it doesn't bring back 700?

Comment: I didn't remove the ) at the end of the query line. Come on you should've picked up on that :P

Answer (score 0):

You did put single quotes around `$xp` in the query, but it is probably a numeric value, not a string. Now you are probably comparing a numeric value with a string.
Try:

```
$find = $db->query("SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE exp >= $xp LIMIT 1");
```